# How make query with unique?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have query:

```
SELECT TOP 20 f.id_service AS f_id_service,
              f.id_city    AS f_id_city,
              f.name       AS f_name,
              f.address    AS f_address,
              f.business   AS f_business,
              f.web        AS f_web,
              f.phone      AS f_phone,
              f.id_firm    AS f_id_firm
FROM   Firm f
       LEFT JOIN Price p
         ON p.id_service = f.id_service
            AND p.id_city = f.id_city
            AND p.id_firm = f.id_firm
WHERE  f.name NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 f.name
                      FROM   Firm f
                      WHERE  f.blocked = '0'
                             AND ( f.name LIKE 'АВТО%'
                                    OR f.phone LIKE 'АВТО%' )
                             AND ( f.phone != ''
                                    OR f.address != '' )
                             AND f.id_city = '73041'
                      ORDER  BY f.name ASC)
       AND f.dogovor = '1'
       AND f.blocked = '0'
       AND ( f.name LIKE 'АВТО%'
              OR f.phone LIKE 'АВТО%' )
       AND ( f.phone != ''
              OR f.address != '' )
       AND f.id_city = '73041
```

Tell me please how make this query that select only unique f.name ?

Comment: Are the `name` values unique in the `Firm` table to begin with? If they are, then it must be the join that produces the duplicates. Do you need that join? It doesn't seem that you do: you are not selecting anything from `Price` or filtering on any of its columns. So just get rid of it. If that's not the case (i.e. of the duplicates come from `Firm` itself), please elaborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the SELECT to this

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 
    f.name as f_name
FROM ...
```

You can't have all columns values but DISTINCT just one of them: it makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
TOP 20 
f.id_service as f_id_service, 
f.id_city as f_id_city, 
f.name as f_name, 
f.address as f_address, 
f.business as f_business, 
f.web as f_web,
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
TOP 20 
f.id_service as f_id_service, 
f.id_city as f_id_city, 
f.name as f_name, 
f.address as f_address, 
f.business as f_business, 
f.web as f_web, 
f.phone as f_phone, 
f.id_firm as f_id_firm FROM Firm f 
left join Price p on p.id_service=f.id_service 
AND p.id_city=f.id_city AND p.id_firm=f.id_firm 
WHERE 
f.name NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 f.name FROM Firm f 
WHERE f.blocked='0' 
AND (f.name LIKE 'АВТО%' OR f.phone LIKE 'АВТО%') 
AND (f.phone !='' OR f.address != '') AND f.id_city='73041' 
ORDER BY f.name ASC ) AND f.dogovor='1' 
AND f.blocked='0' AND (f.name LIKE 'АВТО%' OR f.phone LIKE 'АВТО%') 
AND (f.phone !='' OR f.address != '') 
AND f.id_city='73041'
```

Because all your columns are from the one table, unless `name` is unique in the `firm` table, you can't use DISTINCT like this. You would need to decide on which firm is displayed in the case of duplicates then craft a complex query to achieve that.